# Why won't virt-install command run?

Tags: centos, terminal, kvm, libvirt

When I type the following `virt-install` command into a CentOS 7 terminal, it gives me room to type a second line instead of running the command.

`virt-install` runs other commands on this machine successfully, so I think the problem is with this command in particular.  I keep re-arranging and re-writing it, but I cannot seem to get the command to run.

**What specific changes need to be made to the following command in order for it to run?**

```
[root@remote-host ~]# virt-install --name=centos7-guest --disk path=/home/disk_test.img,size=100 --graphics none --vcpus=1 --memory=2048 --location /tmp/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.0 --initrd-inject=/tmp/vm.ks  --extra-args="ks=file:/vm.ks ip=dhcp console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8”
> ^C
[root@remote-host ~]#
```

Comment: Your closing double quote might not actually be a double quote (`"`)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Good eyes.  That did it.  Thank you.  I would be happy to mark that as accepted and +1 if you write it as an answer.